# Scope for Parent Records Where Children Exist in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a table, Tags, that has a column "parent_id" which indicates whether a tag is a subcategory of another. Not all tags have a parent category.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Tag", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Tag"
end
```

I know how to get tags that **have** a parent category using a scope:

```
scope :with_parent, -> {includes(:subcategories).where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")}
```

Then creating a method in my model that calls `Tag.with_parent.to_a` which returns the following:

```
[#<Tag id: 78, tag: "FirstChildTag", parent_id: 77>, #<Tag id: 79, tag: "SecondChildTag", parent_id: 77>, #<Tag id: 80, tag: "ThirdChildTag", parent_id: 20>]
```

I know this is an easy question, but how do I create a scope for tags that **are** a parent category? So, in this case, I want to return the tags with id = "77" and "20", since they are the parent categories.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't parent categories have a `parent_id = NULL`? So you can query on that. But, this could lead to false positives as you said that not all categories have a parent category, so those would be `NULL` and included in your data set as well.

Comment: Not necessarily. A subcategory could also be a parent of another subcategory in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need not only roots, but also nested 'parents', and there' not many tags in table - try

```
scope :parents, ->{ where(id: where.not(parent_id:nil).ids) }
```

(this is very inefficient if table is large)

But actually it's better to have a field with children count and use counter_cache for it:

```
belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Tag", counter_cache: :children_count
scope :parents, ->{ where(arel_table[:children_count].gt(0))}
```

remember to reset the counter once added

Also in this case you can have 'true roots' scope by additional filtering on parent_id being null

Comment: This sound like what I'm trying to achieve, however, when I try using counter_cache, I get a "stack level too deep" error

Comment: Actually, I also get the same thing when trying to access the roots scope.